# How to take screenshot of screen in flutter when using qr code scanner package

Tags: flutter

I am trying to scan codes using https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner. But I would also like to take the screenshot of the code being scanned. For this I wrapped the QRView widget with RepaintBoundary widget along with a globalkey for it (reference: https://codesearchonline.com/flutter-screenshot/). But this is generating a black color screenshot and not the actual code scanned. I tried to see if pausing the camera(controller.pauseCamera) would make a difference, but it was of no use. I tested the code on a plain widget which had a textbox and it was able to get the correct screenshot of that. But I am not able to get the scanned code screenshot. It always comes in black color. Any help would be appreciated. I don't want the entire screen screenshot as it has appbar and bottombar.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the qr code image to user after the scan in the same scan area simply call controller.stopCamera(); in your _onQRViewCreated method. this will leave the image of the scanned code in view and will look like you took a screenshot.